# generalizing classes or not when using mapper for database

Tags: uml, class-design

lets say i have the following classes:

customer, applicant, agency, partner

i need to work with databases and use mappers to map the objects to the database. my question is, can i generalize these classes with the class person and just implement a mapper for this class? basically it would look like this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

the mapper classes use orm to save and edit fields in the database, i use them because the application i am doing has to be developed further in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each of the classes (`Partner`, `Applicant`, etc.) has different attributes, you can't have only one mapper for all of the classes (well, you can, but then you would have to use meta-programming to retrieve information from the classes lower down the hierarchy). The solution also depends on how and who manages your database: do you have control over how it is designed  or is it something that you cannot change? in the second case I would definitely use a mapper per class to allow full decoupling between DB and app. In the first case, you could use some kind of mapping hierarchy. And also, it depends on what language/frameworks you are using.

Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for the answer. i will be designing the db with an orm framework, but the system as a whole will be developed further in the future, like new modules are going to be added...